# Is there a way to combine bold text from Markdown and a list onto one line without the brackets and quotes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter

So I'm trying to print some bold text and on the same line, I want it to print a list. However, I can't seem to get the list to print without the brackets and quotes on the same line. I can print the bold text and the list with brackets fine but I don't want the brackets and quotes. I am using Markdown to get my bold text

Examples of what I'm getting:
**Genres:** ['Horror', 'Crime'] or

Horror, Crime

**Genres:** None

What I want:
**Genres:** Horror, Crime

```
from IPython.display import Markdown, display
def getGenre():
    genres = []
    all_genres = []
    genre_names = []
    api_key = 'api'
    our_movie_genre_ids =  movies['results'][overview_length].get('genre_ids')
    genre_response = requests.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=' +  api_key + '&language=en-US')
    genre = genre_response.json()
    for i in range(0,len(genre['genres'])):
        all_genres.append(genre['genres'][i].get('id'))
        genre_names.append(genre['genres'][i].get('name'))

    for i in range(0,len(our_movie_genre_ids)):
        for j in range(0,len(all_genres)):
            if our_movie_genre_ids[i] == all_genres[j]:
                genres.append(genre_names[j])
    return str(genres)

def printbold(string):
    display(Markdown(string))

printbold("**Genres:**" + ' ' + getGenre())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to replicate your issue, considering that you are using api call to get the data. But I am assuming that your issue is in the way you handle your list return. Instead of using

```py
return str(genres)
```

in your getGenre() function call, you can try

```py
','.join(genres)
```

to get genres as a string. I hope that helps.

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I needed. I didn't know I could return a function like that. Thank you so much!